# bootstrap datetimepicker dated from another datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 bootstrap datetimepickers, but I want to set the start date on the second from the date I chose for the first, can anyone help me?

```
$('#start_order_date').datetimepicker({
  minView: 2,
  maxView: 2,
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  language: 'pt-BR',
  startDate: new Date()
});   



$('#end_order_date').datetimepicker({
  minView: 2,
  maxView: 2,
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  language: 'pt-BR',
  startDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link multiple pickers together according to [Bootstrap Datepicker's documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers). The following is based off of their example:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(); // Initialize first datepicker
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker(); // Initialize second datepicker

// Listen to date selection event on first datepicker
$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change',function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(e.date);
});

// Listen to date selection event on second datepicker
$('#datetimepicker2').on('dp.change',function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(e.date);
});
```